# Quando a Trigger SQL server é disparada After Insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Quando uma trigger é disparada após um insert e o insert está dentro de uma transação, a trigger é executada no momento do insert ou no fim da transação?

Comment: Do insert é está dentro do transction;

Comment: No momento do INSERT. A transação só é confirmada se todas as instruções DENTRO dela forem concluídas com sucesso. Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-sql-data-warehouse

Comment: @Csorgo é isso mesmo. Se tiver tempo e disposição para fazer a resposta, me marca que votarei nela

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Prontinho. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Trigger é acionada no momento do INSERT. A transação só é confirmada se todas as instruções DENTRO dela forem Concluídas com sucesso.

Segue a dica de um link de referencia para estudo: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-sql-data-warehouse